# Integrate Apache Cassandra Logging with Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, cassandra-2.0

I've this requirement where I need to make use of Cassandra 2.0.x built-in Logging functionality within my spring web application.
Can somebody tell me what all steps do I need to follow to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you connecting remote cassandra server ? or using cassandra as embedded in your spring web app (in same jvm)?

Comment: I'm connecting to a remote cassandra server.